# HTML: Set element attribute equal to another elements attribute

Tags: jquery, html, selector

Is there a way to set this element title `<i title="" id='thei' class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i>` equal to another elements innerHTML?

E.g. `<i title="(#tooltip).innerHTML" id='thei' class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i>`

Pretend this is the #tooltip: `<p id="tooltip">Make this text a title of #thei</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.attr()` , to set `#thei` `"title"` to `#tooltip` `.html()`

```
$("#thei").attr("title", $("#tooltip").html())
```

---

```js
$("#thei").attr("title", $("#tooltip").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p id="tooltip">Make this text a title of #thei</p>
<i title="" id='thei' class='fa fa-check-square-o'>thei</i>
```